# Command Line hash input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a generator class that I can run like this:

```
rails g shopping_template --attributes=email:hello
```

It recognizes email as input. But when I want to add several attributes its not working, it only recognizes email:

rails g shopping_template --attributes=email:hello,name:hans,house:big

**Ho do I have to change `--attributes=email:hello,name:hans,house:big` so that its recognized correctly as a hash?**

Here's the code from the class:

```
class_option :attributes,
             type: :hash,
             default: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Thor document](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki/Method-Options). This is the correct way to pass a hash:

```
--option=name:string age:integer
```

So for your example, it would be:

```
--attributes=email:hello name:hans house:big
```